# Maintaining an animated div present on scene

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying constantly to maintain the div that animates still on the scene whenever the user draws his mouse on top of it.

**HTML**

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="portrait">
            <div id="photo"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="slide">
            <div id="slider">
                <a id="something" class="thisthing">some link here</a>
            </div>
        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
#portrait{
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  top:20px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#slide{
  height:100px;
  border: none;
  padding-left:30px;
}
#slider{
  border: none;
  padding-left:30px;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.thisthing{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#something{
  position:relative;
  left: -25px;
}
```

**JS**

```
 $('#portrait').mouseover(function(){
    $('#slider').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    width: "300px"
  }, 1500, $.noop);
});

 $('#slider').mouseout(function(){
    $('#slider').animate({
    opacity: 0,
    width: "0px"
  }, 1000, $.noop);
});
```

My solution doesn't work well at all, fades badly and lags a lot because as soon as the user leaves the black square the div fades immediately. What I want is to **hover the black square**, **the green div appears** and then **make the div dissapear only IF** `$(/*.mouseout() of the black square OR the green div*/).fadeOut(thegreendiv)`.

**AKA** When you hover the link "some link here" or any other part of the green div I want it to stay there, otherwise fadeout.

http://jsfiddle.net/SVFge/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SVFge/2/)

Use the methods `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of the `over` and `out` and have a bigger zone to mouseleave

**HTML**

```
<table id="hoverOutZone">
  <tr>
    <td id="portrait">
      <div id="photo"></div>
    </td>
    <td id="slide">
      <div id="slider">
        <a id="something" class="thisthing">some link here</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**NEW JS**

```
$('#portrait').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#slider').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: "300px"
    }, 1500);
});

$('#hoverOutZone').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#slider').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        width: "0px"
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: For some reason it's still heavily lagged (hover in and out fast)... Any solution on this?

Comment: what do you mean by laggy?

Comment: I think i know what you mean, take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SVFge/3/

Comment: é isso mesmo Estradinha, obrigadão amor <3